# Are commit templates supported on DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I know that on Git in general it is possible to enable commit templates by modifying the git config file in the .git-folder. But as these folders are hidden in DevOps is this possible or even recommended in DevOps? If it is doable on DevOps is the process different?

In Git the process should be, modify git config to include:

```
[commit]
  template = ~/.gitmessage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with Tomasz, It is default git behavior, it's not Azure DevOps specific.

As a workaround:

1. Enable [branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops), it will reject developers push changes directly to the protected branches. Developers  need create pull request to push the changes.
2. Configure [pull request template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-templates?view=azure-devops) file.
3. Update repo and create pull request to push changes.
4. Use pull request template to update the pull request description.

Then we can check it in the commit details.

Result:

[image]

Comment: "We cannot do this now, you can raise a suggestion ticket." Suggestion ticket would not change that, this is default git behaviour it's not Azure DevOps specific.

Comment: Hi @Tomasz Kaniewski, Thanks for your sharing, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to edit .git/config file and store it in the remote repo, for everyone to clone it.

You can include instruction in ReadMe on your repo to change a config with

```
[commit]
  template = ~/.gitmessage
```

once someone clones it.

Comment: Hi, I'm glad I could help. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. The best way to say "thanks" is to vote on or/and accept an answer.